# cURL send JSON as x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: bash, curl

I want to post the following JSON:

```
{
   "cities": {
       "chicago": 123,
       "boston": 245
   }
}
```

Using `curl` as `x-www-form-urlencoded` without using a .json file. I cannot figure out how to build the `curl -F ...`

Comment: `curl -F 'data={"cities":{"chicago":123,"boston":245}}' ...`

Comment: What name/value pairs does the remote end expect? There's no one input that particular JSON maps to.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you could try:

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://localhost:3000/blahblah
```

Where `param1=value...` have to be your JSON data as `chicago=123&boston=245`

Or explicit form:

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:3000/blahblah
```

Instead of `http://localhost:3000/blahblah` you should provide real URL of your service.

Answer (score 7):

The whole point of `curl -F`, according to the man page, is "to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388." In other words, it's best used when you need to emulate an HTML form with a file input.

Instead use `curl -d` to specify the raw POST data:

```
curl -d '{"cities":{"chicago":123,"boston":245}}' https://example.com
```

If this is actually how they expect data, it is a misconfigured server, as `x-www-form-urlencoded` data should be in the form `key=value`.